# Syntax in python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am new in python  scripting and I trying to figure out w basics about a program source code.

I am struggling to understand these two expressions:

First :
`index = [0]*3`, It creates an index but how?
Second :

`random.random_shuffle(mylist[-1])`, what does `"-1"` mean? The last item in the list?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `index = [0] * 3` does not create an index, it creates a list. And yes, `-1` is the last item in the list. These pieces of information can be found on a very basic Python tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, Do you mean  a list of three  zeros? It is where I am struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are right in one case. Although nothing in your code uses a dictionary. But, maybe these examples will help clear things up.

```
my_zeroes = [0]*3 
assert my_zeroes == [0, 0, 0]
assert [0, 1, 2, 3][-1] == 3
```

- In the first line the syntax you have here will create a list containing three zeroes. Your statement `First : index = [0]*3, It creates an index` doesn't really make sense. Indexes are inherent to certain data structures like lists and tuples, for example, you don't 'create' them as such. But hopefully my example makes it a bit clearer what is happening here.
- In the second line we just check the above fact is true. If it wasn't true it would throw an `AssertionError`, so `assert` is a useful debugging tool.
- In the third line we assert the answer to your second question: `[some_list][-1]` does indeed perform a negative index into the last item of the list. Unless the list in question is empty in which case `[][-1]` will give you an `IndexError`, as will any other index for that matter while trying to index into the empty list.

You can check out the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to get more familiar with the syntax. Good luck!